# MySQL: Group by two columns include zero item counts

Tags: mysql

I'd like to count the total number of "ids" grouped by "date" and "type", if one "date" the "type" doesnt exist print 0.

I have this table:

```
id  type    date
1    0      2015-11-12
2    1      2015-11-12
3    0      2015-11-12
4    0      2016-10-07
5    0      2016-10-07
6    0      2016-12-02
7    1      2017-03-08
8    0      2018-02-01
```

Example what I'd like to see:

```
 COUNT(*)|type| date
   2     |  0 | 2015-11-12
   1     |  1 | 2015-11-12
   2     |  0 | 2016-10-07
   0     |  1 | 2016-10-07
   1     |  0 | 2016-12-02
   0     |  1 | 2016-12-02
   0     |  0 | 2017-03-08
   1     |  1 | 2017-03-08
   1     |  0 | 2018-02-01
   0     |  1 | 2018-02-01
```

I posted the code here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b15329

Please, your help.

Comment: Simple query for getting the data, modify it for your part.
select count(*),type,date from test group by date,type

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is not working yet?

Comment: Have you done anything???  I don't see your solution.  This is a very simple problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
SELECT IFNULL(C.count,0) AS count, D.date, T.type FROM
  (SELECT DISTINCT date FROM test) AS D CROSS JOIN
  (SELECT DISTINCT type FROM test) AS T LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT COUNT(*) AS count, date, type FROM test GROUP BY date, type) AS C
      ON C.date = D.date AND C.type = T.type
ORDER BY D.date, T.type
```

Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b15329/87/0).

Comment: Thanks so much, its the solution!

Answer (score 0):

```
select IFNULL(COUNT(*), 0) AS count,type,date from test group by date,type
```